# Python idiom to return the only element or None

Tags: python, idioms

I've got a list, which may or may not contain a unique element satisfying a given predicate. I am looking for an expression which evaluates to an item satisfying that predicate if it exists *and* is unique, and otherwise returns `None`. Something like

```
numbers = [4, 3, 9, 7, 1, 2, 8]
print(the(item for item in numbers if item > 10))     # None
print(the(item for item in numbers if item % 2 == 0)) # None
print(the(item for item in numbers if item % 7 == 0)) # 7
```

Is there a built-in idiom for this, or do I have to write my own `the` function?

Answer (score 4):

I do not know a single expression way for that, but that simple function should work:

```
def the(it, cond):
    l = [ i for i in it if cond(i) ]
    return l[0] if len(l) == 1 else None
```

Test:

```
>>> print(the(numbers,(lambda x: x > 10)))
None
>>> print(the(numbers,(lambda x: x % 7 == 0)))
7
>>> print(the(numbers,(lambda x: x % 2 == 0)))
None
```

Comment: Could be a single expression by using `(l + [None])[::2][-1]` or `((l + [None]) * 3)[2]`, but I don't really think they're good :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try asking for two elements with [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), would be a bit simpler:

```
def the(it):
    tmp = list(islice(it, 2))
    return tmp[0] if len(tmp) == 1 else None
```

Or a loop:

```
def the(it):
    value = None
    for i, value in enumerate(it):
        if i == 1:
            return None
    return value
```

Or yet another way to use `next`:

```
def the(it):
    first = next(it, None)
    o = object()
    if next(it, o) is o:
        return first
```

Or similar to yours:

```
def the(it):
    first = next(it, None)
    try:
        next(it)
    except:
        return first
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I can just write `the` as

```
def the(it):
    it = iter(it)
    try:
        value = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return None
    try:
        next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return value
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following lazy approach. Get the next two items from the generator expression and return `None` if the second item from the generator is not `None`:

```
def func(lst, pred):
    gen = (i for i in lst if pred(i))
    v, w = next(gen, None), next(gen, None)
    return v if w is None else None


print(func([4, 3, 9, 7, 1, 2, 8], lambda x: x>10))
# None
print(func([4, 3, 9, 7, 1, 2, 8], lambda x: x % 2 == 0))
# None
print(func([4, 3, 9, 7, 1, 2, 8], lambda x: x % 7 == 0))
# 7
print(func([4, 3, 9, 0, 1, 2, 8], lambda x: x % 7 == 0))
# 0
```

Comment: Using a set will remove duplicates. I assume `print(the(item for item in (1,1,2,2) if item % 2 == 0))` should be `None`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Didn't consider that. Updated

Comment: How about `print(func([1, None], lambda x: True))` (prints `1` instead of `None`).

Comment: @StefanPochmann They could use a sentinel instead of `None` and I strongly doubt they have a `None` in their list of *numbers*

Comment: That's only in their example, though. Their question title and text say "element" and their own answer as well as yours look general. Btw, you already have an object that you could use as sentinel: `gen`. I think that would be cool :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yes, I was thinking about this, or how about just using `object()` as the sentinel?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple solution for this problem:

```
def the(items):
    return items[0] if (len(items) == 1) else None

numbers = [4, 3, 9, 7, 1, 2, 8]
print(the([item for item in numbers if item > 10]))     # None
print(the([item for item in numbers if item % 2 == 0])) # None
print(the([item for item in numbers if item % 7 == 0])) # 7
```

You could also apply the following format. It might not be any simpler in terms of code, but it certainly is faster when the item count is large.

```
print(the(list(filter(lambda x: x > 10, numbers))))     # None
print(the(list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, numbers)))) # None
print(the(list(filter(lambda x: x % 7 == 0, numbers)))) # 7
```